# Dynamically loading images in UIImageView from database in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite, uiimageview, uiimage

I have saved my images in database with type BLOB. Now I am extracting these images from database using sql stmt and saving it in a NSData object. see the following code snippet

```
NSData *img = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(loadInfostmt, 4)  length: sqlite3_column_bytes(loadInfostmt, 4)];

self.birdImage = [UIImage imageWithData:img];
```

After getting image I tried setting it at image attribute of UIImageView to load it to image view. I used following techniques but nothing seems to work.

1.

```
self.imgPikr = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:brd.birdImage];  
[self.imgPikr setImage:brd.birdImage];
```

2.

```
[self.imgPikr = [[UIImageView alloc] init];    
self.imgpikr.image = brd.birdImage;
```

3.

```
   [self.imgPikr = [[UIImageView alloc] init];    
   [self.imgpikr setImage:brd.birdImage];
```

Here **imgPikr** is a UIImageView object and birdImage is object of UIImage class.
every other data is displayed in view correctly except the image.
I dont have any error or warning or runtime exception but still cant load image.
Please tell me the solution. I have been working on it since a week. but couldnt find anything working.
Any answer or experimentation is welcomed.

thanx in advance

Comment: did you just leave out the calls where you assign a frame to the UIImageView and add it to your view? Did you use Interface Builder to create your userinterface?

Comment: Are you adding self.imgPikr to a view at some point, or is it declared as an IBOutlet? Or both? Or neither?

Comment: Can you give me the code that you save the image, and can you print out the NSLog(@"%@", image);

Comment: I added UIimageView using interface builder. Also imgPikr is an IBOutlet object. I have ensured that connection are made beteen imgPikr and UIImageView in interface builder.

Comment: When print image wit NSLog ( @" image is%@", self.birdImage); It prints  image is <UIImage: 0x5108480>.

Comment: I problem lies at point of loading images in view. because if I ca print image in console, I am using correct method to retrieve image from database.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 is the best option, since `-[UIImageView initWithImage:]` will automatically resize the imageView to be the same size as the passed image (and it is also unnecessary to `setImage:` if you use this initializer).

However, as @Robot K points out in the comments, you still need to add `self.imgPikr` as a subview of a view that is visible on the screen.

Additionally, if your `imgPikr` property is declared as `(retain)`, then you have a memory leak.

Comment: yes it is (retain). how should I improve it?  Should I use Copy instead. If yes plsease specify reasons as well.

Comment: @Nitesh `autorelease` the new imageview before setting the property. Reason? -> read the memory management guidelines: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html

Comment: thanx dave I will update and upgrade my code. Can you please suggest anything regarding problem i mentioned above. your help is appreciated